# How to setup data-structure for flexible navigation

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I look around but I cannot find a answear for my question, maybe i search with the wrong words...

So, I hope anybody can help me.

I want to store a flexible nested structure of ids into my database for a kind of file-tree.

For the moment I guess, this will be a good idea, but I'm not sure if that is really practial and offer a unlimited flexibility for nesting (sub-folder, sub-sub-folders etc.

```
ID|NAME                        |POSITION |CHILD_OF_ID
-----------------------------------------------------
100 |Folder1                   |1        |null
200 |Folder2                   |2        |null
300 |Sub-Folder of Folder 1    |1        |100
400 |Sub-Folder of Folder 1    |2        |100
400 |Sub-Folder of Sub-Folder 1|1        |300
500 |Folder3                   |2        |100
```

I'm not sure if that really works, after all, I don't know how I should order this data in the easiest way with PHP?

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? I've seen this pattern before almost as-is (`parent_id` vs. `CHILD_OF_ID`).

Comment: i'm not sure if this works well. Also i dont know how i can sort this result from database in php

Comment: Using `SORT BY` as usual. What's the use case you're trying to cover off here?

Comment: I can't post comments yet. About column naming I've seen more parent_id than child_of_id I guess it's a more compact name.